# How to add right tick or wrong tick in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working on `pyqt5` project. I am making the UI in `qt-designer` and then converting its ui file to py file. My project involves enrolling user. So once they are enrolled, I need to show them a message along with a right tick icon. If for some reason they are not enrolled, I need to show the message and a wrong tick. Something like below:

Right tick when enrolled

[image]

Wrong tick when not enrolled:

[image]

I don't seem to find these icons or symbols in `qt-desginer` that's why I thought I would use the images as pixmap on label. The problem with this approach is that, mainwindow background color is blue and these right and wrong icons are in white background which doesn't look good.

Is there any way I can add basic symbols and icons like ticks, temperature and other in `qt-designer`. If not what are the alternatives for this. Please help. Thanks. Using below code to add images:

```
pixmap1 = QPixmap("img/right_tick.jpg")
self.ui.status_label2.setPixmap(pixmap1)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Not sure how I can give you the example source code because I have no idea on how to add icons/symbols.

Comment: Qt Designer does not provide any artwork. You'll need to find a high quality PNG file with a transparent background. Alternatively, you might be able to find an SVG file. You can use a label as a canvas to hold your picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As in picture above. (Picture worths 10 characters.)